# Odd problem with spacing using memoir when switching from oneside to twoside

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, memoir, double-sided

For reasons I won't bore anyone with, I being forced to change my document at the last minute from `oneside` to `twoside` using `memoir`.  However, when I do, I suddenly get odd problems with spacing;  the title pages have the entire page's text shifted to the bottom, and the last subsection or paragraph in each chapter is moved to the bottom of the page as well (leaving a huge chunk of vertical whitespace between the last and the penultimate paragraph).  I'm sorry, I'd like to provide a minimal working example, but I can't come up with one, so I'm just hoping that someone can point me in the direction of general things to check.  Here's some possibly relevant code, though it's a long document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4,twoside]{memoir}
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{30}
\strictpagecheck
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;} 


\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{3cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{4cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

...

\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]
\include{foreword}
\pagestyle{plain}
\mainmatter
\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]
\include{chap1}

...
```

and so on.

Comment: Try to add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoted from the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (p 5):

> When the `twoside` or `twocolumn` option is selected then typesetting is
>   done with `\flushbottom`, otherwise it is done with `\raggedbottom`.
>
> When `\raggedbottom` is in effect LaTeX makes little attempt to keep a
>   constant height for the typeblock; pages may run short.
>
> When `\flushbottom` is in effect LaTeX ensures that the typeblock on
>   each page is a constant height, except when a page break is
>   deliberately introduced when the page might run short. In order to
>   maintain a constant height it may stretch or shrink some vertical
>   spaces (e.g., between paragraphs, around headings or around ﬂoats or
>   other inserts like displayed maths). This may have a deleterious
>   effect on the color of some pages. If you get too many strung out
>   pages with `\flushbottom` you may want to put `\raggedbottom` in the
>   preamble.

As such, use `\raggedbottom` to avoid flushing text flush with the lower part of the text block.

Comment: Thanks, Werner!  It was probably a simple answer for you, but that saved me a gigantic headache.