# Unwanted automatical rearrangement using twoside

Tags: spacing, double-sided

I'm writing a thesis and have a problem with the *twoside* command. I wrote the whole thing using just oneside, but when I switched to twoside, it automatically inserted spaces between paragraphs, figures and tables on pages with more space than needed (instead of a blank space at the end of the page).
Has anyone had this problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Posting a MWE would be useful. Perhaps try `\raggedbottom` in your preamble.

Comment: I have a pretty long preample and am not sure what everything does, so i didnt add any example.. anyway, \raggedbottom did the job! many thanks to you, @AML!

Comment: okay I'll add it as the answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `\raggedbottom` to the preamble should fix your spacing issues.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34320/121944) is a more complete explanation about it.