# How to avoid the vertical spacing dispersion in the whole document?

Tags: xetex, texlive, ctex

I found that LaTeX automatically disperses the spacing in the vertical direction, which is similar to the vertical version of  Justify or Distributed in word. This will lead to a problem, that is, when browsing documents, it will be obvious that the positions of the first-level titles of different pages are jumping. I would like to ask how to avoid this problem, and whether I can make the distance between the first-level title and the top of the document fixed.

In order to prove the existence of this phenomenon, I conducted the following tests. There are two documents, `1.tex` and `2.tex` respectively:

```latex
% 1.tex
\documentclass[zihao=-4]{ctexbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\end{document}
```

```latex
% 2.tex
\documentclass[zihao=-4]{ctexbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\section{章节}
文本测试文本测试文本测试文本
\end{document}
```

The only difference is the content of the penultimate chapter, which I compiled with XeLaTeX under TeX Live 2021. For the convenience of comparison, I used `mutool` to merge the first pages of `1.pdf` and `2.pdf` into one pdf, and opened it in a two-page view. We can clearly see that the contents at the top will change in position due to the difference in the contents at the bottom. If the contents of `1.tex` and `2.tex` documents are less than one page, this phenomenon will not happen, because there is no need to disperses the spacing in the vertical direction.

[image: combine 1.pdf and 2.pdf]

Comment: you could try `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: There is a reason why this is done so. Add a figure between one of the sections and you will see what happens you will lose the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason has been explained in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34315/odd-problem-with-spacing-using-memoir-when-switching-from-oneside-to-twoside/34320#34320). Users can switch between the two page breaking mechanisms by adding `\raggedbottom` or `flushbottom` in preamble.

`\raggedbottom`  is default in `oneside` option, and `\flushbottom` is default in `twoside` option.