# Problem with changing space before and after specific environments

Tags: spacing, environments

Short story : environments crafted for class article create chaotic spaces before and after the places I use them now that I have switched to scrbook.

Long story : I am writing a phd thesis on LaTeX, and I cite interviews and scenes I have witnessed in specific environments, "verbatimlong" and "carnetethno". These environments are meant to make clear the changes between main text and this material, with a reduced space between lines and increased margins.

I know that this process was probably a mistake, but I wrote in separate documents (class : article). Now I have to change to a masterdocument with koma-script (class: scrbook), and one of the problem I encounter is that spaces before and after these environments change without apparent reasons.

Here's a MWE illustrating the environments :

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{verbatimlong}[1][]{
    empty,
    before upper*={
        \newcommand{\transfert}{#1}
        \setstretch{1.1}
        \og
    },
    after upper*={
        \fg\par\textsc{\transfert}
    },
}

\newtcolorbox{carnetethno}[1][]{
    empty,
    before upper*={
        \newcommand{\transfert}{#1}
        \setstretch{1.1}
        
    },
    after upper*={
        \par\textsc{\transfert}
    },
}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[52]
    
    \begin{verbatimlong}[Extrait d'entretien]
        \lipsum[15]
    \end{verbatimlong}
    
    \lipsum[53]
    
    \begin{carnetethno}[Extrait de carnet de terrain]
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{carnetethno}
    
    
    
    \lipsum[54]
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

I guess there's a problem with using newtcolorbox with scrbook, hence I tried with \newenvironment, \addmargin and \setstretch, but having poor LaTeX-writing skills it doesn't work better...

Edit : As Jlab suggested, I kept using `tcolorbox` but made the two environments `breakable` so that filling automatically the pages doesn't come with huge spaces between paragraph (ref : section 19.3 "Main Option Keys" of the tcolorbox manual).

Comment: I don't see a problem. Do you also get this output: https://i.imgur.com/AiWxPcN.png? Can you explain, which spaces are wrong? Otherwise I could only guess, that I misunderstood something or your example does not show the problem, maybe a problem like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34315/277964.

Comment: Off-topic: `twoside` is the default with almost all book classes, i.e., `scrbook` and `book`. So you can remove the explicit option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I understand, your question is about the vertical spaces before and after your tcolorboxes. LaTeX stretches the space between paragraphs to fill vertically the page and since the classes `book`  and `scrbook` haven't the same page geometry, it's rendered differently. Test with `\raggedbottom` (this disables the vertical filling of the page): I get the same spaces before and after the tcolorboxes for the two classes.

Comment: @cabohah : Sorry I forgot to clarify this : the MWE works just fine, but my document doesn't (and duely noted for the twoside option !)

Comment: @jlab : Thanks a lot ! That's exactly the thing I didn't understand and that was causing my troubles : I wasn't used to LaTeX behavior about vertical filling with scrbook, and \raggedbottom gives something much closer to what I was expecting.

Comment: @Hobo_academicus The `article` class  also vertically fill the page. I do not recommend `\raggedbottom`, it was just a check. As defined, your tcolorboxes are not breakable, LaTeX has to stretch excessively the spaces when a box is returned to the next page  (you should get some `Underfull \vbox` errors). Maybe it would be better to make your boxes `breakable` (see section 19.3 "Main Option Keys" of the tcolorbox manual) or treat them as `float` (section 4.13 "Floating Objects").

Comment: @jlab Right sorry I misinterpreted the test ; I followed your adive and made the two environments `breakable`, and it works a lot better now.

Comment: @Hobo_academicus Please note: A minimal working example in a question should show the problem. Otherwise it is not really helpful but misleading.